# adding A* path planning algorithm as plugin

Tags: ros, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using ROS indigo.i am using gmapping to obtain the map.i wrote my A* path planning algorithm in python.someone please help me to integrate this.when i searched [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS).But it is written in c++.someone please help..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227628/adding-a*-path-planning-algorithm-as-plugin/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As move_base and thus also the [BaseGlobalPlanner](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_core/html/classnav__core_1_1BaseGlobalPlanner.html) interface are written in C++ you can't trivially inject your Python code there. Here are a few options I see:

- Use the already available A* implementation (see [global_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner)) and not your own.
- Manually reimplement in C++ (or try some sort of Python to C++ tool, but I'd expect that to be more of a timesink than anything else)
- Implement a thin BaseGlobalPlanner plugin that calls your Python planner running in it's own external (rospy) ROS node, for instance via a service call. In that case, the C++ plugin doesn't do more than forwarding the request outside and then forwarding the response via the planner interface.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0